# Caching images present in database

Tags: java, image, jsp, caching

I store images having unique id's in database as BLOB and display them in jsp pages by streaming them from the database. Wondering if there is a way to cache images so that i don't have to incur the latency due to streaming off of database. I would recommend if someone presents some snippet/example in order to achieve caching of images.

Comment: Can't you just store them in files along with the DB blobs?  That way you could lookup the name/location and access them from a (hopefully) less encumbered disk.

Comment: That would be candidate for mismtach. I want to avoid having images in two places and would rather have them in database so that it is easy to port them.

Comment: well, I'm saying that you could store them in DB, and store them in files too.  It would take twice the space, but until you want to port them you can use the DB as backup and the files for faster retrieval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what part of the process you need help with, but here's what I would do:

First you have to create a class to hold the cache and metadata.  Let's call it ImageCache.  Of course you need a String for the image name and a byte[] to hold the image contents itself.  Then add a collection of them in the class that currently extracts the images from the database.  When an image request comes in, search through the collection for the filename. If found, just send the byte[] back. If it's not in the collection, read it from the db then create a new ImageCache object from it and add it to the collection.

For bonus points, include a Date lastAccessed field and a Comparator.  The Comparator and the date field will let you maintain the cache.  Let's say your cache can hold 50 images (based on available memory).  Your Comparator can be used to sort the collection of ImageCache objects in [LRU (Least Recently Used)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used) order, sorting by lastAccesed in ascending order.  When the collection reaches the maximum entries, find the entry with the oldest lastAccessed, and replace it.  That will give you the best cache hit rate while not taking all the heap memory.

Another option is to just use Hibernate as an abstraction layer between the program and the database.  This will offer many benefits, one of which will be highly configurable and completely automatic caching.

Answer (score 0):

Just slap nginx (a http caching reverse proxy) in front of the web server. The code's already been written, so just use it.